# error when trying to create a scheduled job in azure ml

Tags: azure, environment, azureml-python-sdk

im getting this error when submitting a scheduled pipeline,
Failed to submit job due to Exception: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Exception(s) encountered while validating environment definition. See inner exception for details. ().
Microsoft.RelInfra.Common.Exceptions.ErrorResponseException: Exception(s) encountered while validating environment definition. See inner exception for details. (BaseImage, BaseDockerfile, or BuildContext must be set for Docker-based environments.) (Conda dependencies were not specified. Please make sure that conda dependencies are specified in your run configuration.).
here is my code

```
from azureml.core import Experiment, ScriptRunConfig, Environment, Workspace
from azureml.core.compute import ComputeTarget, AmlCompute
from azureml.core.compute_target import ComputeTargetException
from azureml.core.runconfig import RunConfiguration
from azureml.pipeline.core import Pipeline, ScheduleRecurrence, Schedule
import datetime
ws = Workspace.from_config()

cluster_name = "cpu-cluster"

try:
    compute_target = ComputeTarget(workspace=ws, name=cluster_name)
    print(f'Found existing cluster, use it: {cluster_name}')
except ComputeTargetException:
    print(f"{cluster_name} not found")
env = Environment.from_conda_specification(name='job-env', file_path='job-env.yml')
from azureml.pipeline.steps import PythonScriptStep

# Assuming `compute_target` and `env` are already defined
script_step = PythonScriptStep(
    name="Run Python Script",
    script_name="search.py",
    compute_target=compute_target,
    source_directory="./",
    runconfig=env,
    allow_reuse=True
)

experiment = Experiment(workspace=ws, name='search_experiment2')

from azureml.core import Experiment
from azureml.pipeline.core import Pipeline

pipeline = Pipeline(workspace=ws, steps=[script_step])
published_pipeline = pipeline.publish(
    name="search_pipeline_2",
    description="Pipeline Description",
    continue_on_step_failure=False)
from azureml.pipeline.core import Schedule, ScheduleRecurrence

recurrence = ScheduleRecurrence(frequency="Day", interval=1)  # Define your recurrence pattern

schedule = Schedule.create(
    workspace=ws, 
    name="DailyScriptRun",
    description="Daily run of script",
    pipeline_id=published_pipeline.id,
    experiment_name="searchExperimentName",
    recurrence=recurrence)
```

and here is my env yml file

```
name: job-env
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.10
  - pip=21.2.4
  - pip:
    - aenum==3.1.15
    - aiohttp==3.9.3
    - aiosignal==1.3.1
    - annotated-types==0.6.0
    - anyio==4.3.0
    - appdirs==1.4.4
    - APScheduler==3.10.4
    - attrs==23.2.0
    - azure-ai-documentintelligence==1.0.0b2
    - azure-ai-formrecognizer==3.3.2
    - azure-ai-textanalytics==5.3.0
    - azure-common==1.1.28
    - azure-core==1.30.1
    - azure-identity==1.15.0
    - azure-keyvault-secrets==4.8.0
    - azure-search==1.0.0b2
    - azure-search-documents==11.6.0b2
    - azure-storage-blob==12.19.1
    - azure-storage-file-datalake==12.14.0
    - beautifulsoup4==4.12.3
    - bs4==0.0.2
    - case_conversion==2.1.0
    - certifi==2024.2.2
    - cffi==1.16.0
    - chardet==5.2.0
    - charset-normalizer==3.3.2
    - clipboard==0.0.4
    - colorama==0.4.6
    - colour==0.1.5
    - contourpy==1.2.0
    - cryptography==42.0.5
    - cursor==1.3.5
    - cycler==0.12.1
    - decorator==4.4.2
    - dill==0.3.8
    - distro==1.9.0
    - fonttools==4.49.0
    - frozenlist==1.4.1
    - fuzzywuzzy==0.18.0
    - gender-guesser==0.4.0
    - h11==0.14.0
    - html-text==0.5.2
    - httpcore==1.0.4
    - httpx==0.27.0
    - idna==3.6
    - imageio==2.34.0
    - imageio-ffmpeg==0.4.9
    - infi.systray==0.1.12
    - inflect==7.0.0
    - isodate==0.6.1
    - kiwisolver==1.4.5
    - lxml==5.1.0
    - matplotlib==3.8.3
    - maybe-else==0.2.1
    - mbstrdecoder==1.1.3
    - moviepy==1.0.3
    - msal==1.27.0
    - msal-extensions==1.1.0
    - msoffcrypto-tool==5.3.1
    - msrest==0.7.1
    - multidict==6.0.5
    - numpy==1.26.4
    - O365==2.0.34
    - oauthlib==3.2.2
    - office365==0.3.15
    - Office365-REST-Python-Client==2.5.6
    - olefile==0.47
    - openai==1.7.1
    - packaging==24.0
    - pandas==2.2.1
    - parsedatetime==2.6
    - pathmagic==0.3.14
    - pillow==10.2.0
    - portalocker==2.8.2
    - prettierfier==1.0.3
    - proglog==0.1.10
    - pycparser==2.21
    - pydantic==2.6.3
    - pydantic_core==2.16.3
    - pydub==0.25.1
    - pyinstrument==4.6.2
    - pyiotools==0.3.18
    - PyJWT==2.8.0
    - pymiscutils==0.3.14
    - PyMuPDF==1.23.25
    - PyMuPDFb==1.23.22
    - pyparsing==3.1.2
    - pypdf==4.1.0
    - PyPDF2==3.0.1
    - pyperclip==1.8.2
    - PyQt5==5.15.10
    - PyQt5-Qt5==5.15.2
    - PyQt5-sip==12.13.0
    - pysubtypes==0.3.18
    - python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
    - python-docx==1.1.0
    - python-dotenv==1.0.1
    - pytz==2024.1
    - pywin32==306
    - readchar==4.0.5
    - regex==2023.12.25
    - requests==2.31.0
    - requests-oauthlib==1.4.0
    - Send2Trash==1.8.2
    - simplejson==3.19.2
    - six==1.16.0
    - sniffio==1.3.1
    - soupsieve==2.5
    - stringcase==1.2.0
    - tabulate==0.9.0
    - tenacity==8.2.3
    - tiktoken==0.6.0
    - tqdm==4.66.2
    - typepy==1.3.2
    - typing_extensions==4.10.0
    - tzdata==2024.1
    - tzlocal==5.2
    - urllib3==2.2.1
    - XlsxWriter==3.2.0
    - yarl==1.9.4
```

the error indicates that the problem in environment
also what im trying to do is nothing related to ML but i want to use compute cluster because my script will take at least 1h of running , is this the best way to do it ?